# REST proxy in Meteor

Tags: javascript, rest, proxy, meteor

I built a simple proxy using Meteor and its Iron Router. It currently fails at passing through other than 200 or 500 status codes, which I guess suffices. Is this `proxy.js` the best way to bypass [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) without modifying remote or Apache/Nginx server settings?

```
"use strict"

// call with "/proxy?url=" + encodeURIComponent(myUrl)
Router.route('/proxy', function(){
    var url = this.params.query.url
    console.log("proxy called with url:", url)
    /* // whitelist url
    if(!/^https:\/\/[a-z]+\.otherdomain\.com\/[a-zA-Z/.]+$/.test(url)){
        var msg = "url not allowed: " + url
        console.log(msg)
        //throw new Meteor.Error(msg)  // Too much scary stacktrace.
        this.response.writeHead(403, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        this.response.end(msg)
    }
    */
    console.log("calling url:", url)
    var r = Meteor.http.call("GET", url)
    var keys = []; for(var k in r) keys.push(k)
    console.log("result has:", keys)
    console.log("result statusCode:", r.statusCode, typeof(r.statusCode))
    console.log("result data:", r.data)
    //this.response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})  // broken?! https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1055
    this.response.writeHead(r.statusCode, r.headers)
    var html = r.content
    // fix relative URLs
    if(html.indexOf('<base ') < 0) html = html.replace(/<head>/i, '<head><base href="'+url+'">')
    this.response.end(html)
}, {where: 'server'})
```